# Org-mode :results file hook to launch file

Tags: org-mode, hooks, babel

My scenario

- python code creating a wav file
- last line of code returns the written file name
- org-mode src block with the option `:results file`

The result block correctly links to the audio file, and I can easily click it and play it.

My question is if it would be possible to add a hook, and if the resulted file has a `.wav` extension to automatically launch it (and will be opened by the OS default audio player)

Or could be more generic: if you can have a hook like `org-babel-after-execute-hook` but having access to the `result` if it's a file or not, the filename, or the contents etc..